# Git doesn't show how many commits ahead of origin I am, and I want it to

Tags: git

There are plenty of questions here about Git saying people are ahead of a remote branch by X commits, and they want it to stop.

I have the opposite problem.  I want Git to tell me how many commits ahead I am, but it doesn't.

When I created my remote bare repository first, then cloned from it, this worked.  In my current case I created the local repository first, then cloned it (bare) to the remote.

This set up my local repository as the remote for the bare repository.  But I removed that, and manually added the remote repository reference to my local.  Pushing works fine.  But I don't see the "You are ahead by X commits" message.  How can I get it?

Comment: +1 great question (love the title) ... I need this too

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`git branch --set-upstream local origin/remote`

*local* and *remote* are the names of your local resp. remote branches.

In Git version 1.8 and later, it's even easier.  Make sure you're on the local branch, and then:

`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/remote`

Comment: You'll have to run `git fetch origin` to get the latest info.

Comment: `git fetch` (with no arguments) defaults to fetching from origin.

Comment: when you get a branch from remote do 'git checkout -t origin/branch-name'. when you push a local branch for the first time do 'git push -u origin branch-name'. Tracking will be set up.

Comment: Totally nitpicky, but I think you mean origin/branch in this example.  Isn't origin the remote in this case?  At any rate, thanks as this helped me out!

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, _local_ and _remote_ are simply placeholders for the respective branch names and do not refer to the git concepts.

Comment: I tried it and no longer works on the newer git verssion. it expect `--track` or `-u`.

Answer (score 8):

I found that there's a way to make this behavior the default:

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge always
```

Despite the name, this doesn't *force* you to always merge branches; you can still rebase if you want to.

It *will* ensure that any time you create a new branch, you'll automatically be able to see how many commits different it is from the branch it was created from.

Comment: Note: In current git versions, this option defaults to true anyway (see man git-config). So you only need to set it if you changed it before (or possibly in old versions of git).

Comment: @sleske while that's correct, there's a subtle distinction between `true` and `always`.  `always` also shows the ahead/behind for local branches, not just remote branches.  I find it useful to set it to `always`.

Comment: @NickDesaulniers: True, that's something I overlooked.